# jqGrid in IE9 wont display data

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jqgrid

I cannot determine what is the cause of why the data is not displayed in jqGrid when using IE 9 and 8.
This is how I initialize my grid and give it data:

```
    $(function(){
            $("#userlist").jqGrid({
                //data: {},
                datatype : "local",
                jsonReader : {
                    repeatitems : false,
                    id : "id"
                },
                colNames:[
                            '',
                            'NAme',
                            'Address',

                         ],
                colModel:[
                            {name:'id',index:'id', hidden:true},
                            {name:'name',index:'name', width:300},
                            {name:'add',index:'add', hidden:true},

                        ],
                autowidth: true,
                sortname: 'id',
                multiselect: true,
                multiboxonly: true,
                rowList:[10,50,100],
                rowNum:10,
                height:250,
                pager: '#userlist',
                viewrecords: true,
            });

            loadData();
    });

    function loadData(){
        var obj = getObjSomewhere();
        .
        .
        .
        console.log(obj.users.length);
        //obj.users  -> array of objects for jqgrid

        if(obj.users != undefined){
            var ugrid = $("#userlist");
            ugrid.clearGridData();
            ugrid.setGridParam({data: obj.users, datatype : 'local'});
            ugrid.trigger("reloadGrid");
        }

    }
```

It works on other browsers, and I cant find any errors in the console. 
Also, I checked that the obj.users has data.
However, I have a function that adds users to that grid. When I do the adding of users, 
the newly added user will be displayed. It is only on the initial load that the existing users will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that it's well-known problem in jqGrid 4.7. I recommend you download the latest version of **free jqGrid** (post 4.8) from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). It contains fixes and performance improvements. You can read more about free jqGrid in [readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) and [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki). You try the code first of all using RawGit service and including URLs which load the files direct from GitHub `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css`, `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js`, `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js` (see [the part of wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit)). Alternatively you can use old version of jqGrid: version 4.6.